# Run Windows 7 in (K)ubuntu without reinstalling it?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, virtualization, emulation

I've got a windows 7 system and are willing to install kubuntu 12.04 64bit on it now.
As I need to run some windows programs I'm willing to keep my windows 7 and setup a dual-boot.

For increasing productivity I'm asking myself if it's possible to boot my already available windows 7 in some kind of virtual box after I've boated Kubuntu.

For clarification of my question: with vm-ware for example you normaly have to make a fresh install of windows 7 for virtualization, but I want to use my already on the hdd installed windows 7.

Comment: What you want is indeed possible.  There are many tutorials on doing exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Surely I'd a look @ google, but I indeed wasn't able to find any of these tutorials. Maybee you could help me out with this, please?

Comment: See: [Booting a native Windows install in Virtualbox: is it possible?](http://serverfault.com/questions/241678/booting-a-native-windows-install-in-virtualbox-is-it-possible)

Comment: Slightly off topic, but have you tried [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)? might be quicker to get going etc for many programs, can probably run them from the windows partition directly

Answer (score -1):

What you are saying is possible, however, whether you use virtualbox or vm-ware you must ensure that the VM is shut down before you boot into the actual partition. if you don't, over time, your windows partition/install will become corrupted. a simple google search should help you find tutorials on how to use a physical dish in virtualbox or vm-ware